# Understanding CPU Utilisation Graph for a task running AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu-usage, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a task defined with 0.5vCPU. It has two containers with 0.25vCPU

Can someone explain to me what the below CPU Utilization graph represents?

[image]

The above graph is from Health and Metrics section in AWS Console for the sevice.

Since each of my containers has 0.25 vCPU it is expected that the container gets at most 25% of a CPU core every second. Then what does ~115% (max CPU utilisation) mean in the above graph?

Should not the container be killed when it reaches 100% CPU Utilisation? Why is the max cpu utilisation showing more than 100%?

Comment: I suspect you're getting 100% of the 0.25vCPUs you've provisioned.

Comment: Yes that's what's my understanding also. Then should not the container be killed when it breaches 100%? I am running without auto-scaling on.

Comment: My quick research suggests Fargate doesn't burst, but maybe it does a tiny bit? Otherwise it could be a graphing error. The only way to know for sure might be to ask AWS Support.